# Sagepay payment issues

Tags: opayo

i am trying to fix sagepay payment and receiving few issues,

first when i select sagepay then it auto generate and show name (like this Cuyike Xopuyo) automatically in name field. is there any virus?

second in log file i can see these error messages. what these error means?

2015-09-28T11:45:43+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/HSBC/Model/Remote.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2015-09-28T11:45:43+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/HSBC/Model/Remote.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2015-09-28T11:45:43+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/HSBC/Model/Remote.php' for inclusion (include_path='/public_html/app/code/local:/public_html/app/code/community:/public_html/app/code/core:/public_html/lib:.:/opt/php54/lib/php')  in public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question :

Your error messages relate to an old payment module extension you had installed for HSBC by a company called [studioforty9](http://www.studioforty9.com). You should delete all references to it from your mysql database with the following mysql query :

```
DELETE FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%payment/HSBC/%';
```